# SQL UPDATE Statement in excel VBA not working ( mismatch error )

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have error msg " data type mismatch in criteria expression. " when I try to use the code below

```
Call Connect_to_db
strSQL = "UPDATE StockTable " & _
         "SET [Selected] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("e" & x) & "' " & _
         "WHERE [OwnerName] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("a" & x) & "' " & _
         "AND [OwnerShipMethod] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("b" & x) & "' " & _
         "AND [StockName] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("c" & x) & "' " & _
         "AND [Quantity] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("d" & x) & "' "
         Debug.Print strSQL
cn.Execute strSQL
Call Close_db
```

Comment: and what you get as a result of this line: `Debug.Print strSQL`?

Comment: What data types are involved in this? We cannot smell what data yuo are trying to insert into what kind of columns, and somewhere there is data in your sheet that does not fit into some column in your database. Without knowing how you defined your database, and knowing what data yuo are trying to put in, we know nothing more than what the error tells you. Also, as I asked earlier, and as @KazJaw mentions, show the contents of strSQL.

Comment: @KazJaw Debug.Print strSQL : UPDATE StockTable SET [Selected] = 'True' WHERE [OwnerName] = 'Ali' AND [OwnerShipMethod] = 'direct' AND [StockName] = 'NFK' AND [Quantity] = '2052'

Comment: @oerkelens OwnerName Text
OwnerShipMethod Text
StockName Text
Quantity  Number
Selected Text

Comment: Well, there you go :) You are comparing the _string_ '2052' to the numeric field `Quantity`. If you would have added this vital information to your original question, maybe you would have noticed already by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, removed two ' from my previous answer, which i would not have put there knowing a bit more about the data :)

This shoudl work then, i guess :)

```
Call Connect_to_db
strSQL = "UPDATE StockTable " & _
     "SET [Selected] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("e" & x) & "' " & _
     "WHERE [OwnerName] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("a" & x) & "' " & _
     "AND [OwnerShipMethod] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("b" & x) & "' " & _
     "AND [StockName] = '" & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("c" & x) & "' " & _
     "AND [Quantity] = " & Sheets("InfoStockDes").Range("d" & x) 
Debug.Print strSQL
cn.Execute strSQL
Call Close_db
```